# Rails system tests are running without assets loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run system tests, the browser loads to run the tests but it looks like there's no CSS/JS loaded at all. All of the styles are missing, and tests that involve jQuery/JS fail.

These tests were working and loading fine at one point, I have no idea what has changed.

I've tried running `RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:precompile`, and that didn't seem to fix the issue.

I know someone's going to complain that there's "not enough information here to help" or whatever, but if I knew what information was needed, I would not be here asking :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some assets that were being loaded via CDN. It was actually a network issue on my VM, since I had configured my VM to use a static IP just recently. The assets loaded via CDN did not resolve.

I discovered this by looking in the browser's console.